# Orange and white stripes on Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-10, installation, bitlocker, bootable-media

I'm trying to install Windows 10 in a laptop, but when I boot Windows 10 from a bootable USB stick, vertical orange and white stripes appear in the screen. I've been looking for information on this and it's said to be caused by Bitlocker.

If I typed the correct password, this screen would dissapear. The problem is that how am I going to type my bitlocker password if I haven't set it yet?

P.D. I can't solve this either by running a command in the CMD as I don't have any OS installed in my laptop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After adding some more ram and then updating drivers I started experiencing BSOD and then windows would not boot saying I need to repair windows with a windows cd/usb. On another computer I created a windows installation usb but I too was unable to boot from the usb getting these white/orange vertical lines. After reseating and then removing ram sticks to no avail I finally stumbled on this [forum thread](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1318171-orange-screen-with-vertical-white-lines/?do=findComment&comment=15300597) which mentioned to **reset your BIOS**. Well I did that and windows started booting just fine; didn't even need to reinstall windows anymore.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1181470)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue of orange and white stripes when trying to install Windows 10 22H2 on a new drive in a computer that ran it fine before.

Changing TPM and various other settings to legacy only changed the outcome to a blue screen which then caused the PC to turn off without doing anything.

**The issue for me was, frustratingly, Microsoft's own Media Creation Tool.** Creating an installation USB drive simply did not work, likely because of the used settings, or because the transfer/write somehow failed.

**I used the Media Creation Tool to just download the ISO and then used Rufus** (tool for creating bootable USB drives) **to actually prepare the USB drive.** The installation worked *immediately*.

From what I recall, this isn't even the first time MCT failed me. I just use it seldomly enough to unfortunately forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

That looks as if the internal harddisk (or SSD) in the laptop isn't empty.
It already has a Windows installation on it with BitLocker. (Or a not correctly wiped leftover of such an installation.)
And you are trying to boot into THAT install instead of booting from the USB stick.

2 things to do:
 - Make sure the BIOS is set to boot from USB FIRST, before trying the internal disk.
 - Get a copy of DBAN or other wipe tool en use that first to properly wipe the internal disk.

On or the other should solve your problem.

Comment: The harddisk should be empty as it's a brand new laptop, and I've really make sure that i'm booting from usb, don't know what's happening

Comment: Your Windows 10 image on the stick. Is this recent ? (The 1604 build or later ?) If not get a fresh image. Pre-1604 build are known to have this issue. Try various TPM settings in Bios (TPM enabled/disabled, switch TPM between V2.0 and V1.2 if possible).  Enabling/disabling SecureBoot and/or CSM/Legacy support might also help.

Comment: I tried it with a more recent build and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The USB is most likely corrupt. Grab a new USB drive with 4gb+ and create a new windows 10 boot USB using the windows media creation tool.

I ordered a boot USB off amazon and that's what I ended up having to do.